# How to find which object has the largest value in the most elegant way?

Tags: java, oop

So I've this assignment of coding a Lucky Racer Game in Java, strictly following the constraints of OOP and writing a maintainable / elegant code. There are 5 cars (objects), with random speeds in every round (there are 10 total rounds) and after 10 rounds, I need to find which car (object) covered the most Total Distance i.e which car won the race. Since it's an automatic car, I'm updating gears at each speed entry too - irrelevant info but thought I might explain the context before I show the code.

So here is **AutomaticCar.java** (Class):

```
public class AutomaticCar {
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private int speed;
    private int gear;
    private int odoMeter;
    private totalDistance = 0;
    private gearAverage = 0;


    public AutomaticCar(String model, int year) {
        setModel(model);
        setYear(year);
    }

    
    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        if (speed < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid speed - please try again.");
        } else {
            this.speed = speed;
            setGear();
        }
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setOdoMeter(int currentRound) {
        odoMeter = (currentRound * speed);
        setTotalDistance(odoMeter);
    }

    public int getOdoMeter() {
        return odoMeter;
    }

    public void setTotalDistance(int odoMeter) {
        totalDistance += odoMeter;
    }

    public int getTotalDistance() {
        return totalDistance;
    }

    public void setGear () {
        if (speed > 0 && speed <= 100) {
            gear = 1;
        } else if (speed >= 101 && speed <= 200) {
            gear = 2;
        } else if (speed >= 201 && speed <= 300) {
            gear = 3;
        } else if (speed >= 301 && speed <= 400) {
            gear = 4;
        } else if (speed > 401 && speed <= 500) {
            gear = 5;
        }

        gearAverage += gear;
    }

    public int getGear () {
        return gear;
    }

    public int gearAverage() {
        return (gearAverage/10);
    }

    public String printDashes(int distance) {
        int dashesToPrint = (int)(distance/100);
        String storedDashes = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < dashesToPrint; i++) {
            storedDashes = (storedDashes + "-");
        }
        return storedDashes;
    }

    public void declareWinner() {

    }


}
```

**Main Class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class LuckyRacer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        String model;
        int year;
        int totalRounds = 10;
        int currentRound;

        System.out.println("Enter Car Model & Year for Car One");
        model = input.nextLine();
        year = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        AutomaticCar car1 = new AutomaticCar(model, year);
        car1.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));

        System.out.println("Enter Car Model & Year for Car Two");
        model = input.nextLine();
        year = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        AutomaticCar car2 = new AutomaticCar(model, year);
        car2.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));

        System.out.println("Enter Car Model & Year for Car Three");
        model = input.nextLine();
        year = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        AutomaticCar car3 = new AutomaticCar(model, year);
        car3.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));

        System.out.println("Enter Car Model & Year for Car Four");
        model = input.nextLine();
        year = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        AutomaticCar car4 = new AutomaticCar(model, year);
        car4.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));

        System.out.println("Enter Car Model & Year for Car Five");
        model = input.nextLine();
        year = input.nextInt();
        AutomaticCar car5 = new AutomaticCar(model, year);
        car5.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));

        for (currentRound = 1; currentRound <= totalRounds; currentRound++) {

            car1.setOdoMeter(currentRound);
            car2.setOdoMeter(currentRound);
            car3.setOdoMeter(currentRound);
            car4.setOdoMeter(currentRound);
            car5.setOdoMeter(currentRound);

            System.out.println("After " + currentRound + " hour/s");
            System.out.println("Car 1 " + car1.printDashes(car1.getOdoMeter()) + " :" + car1.getOdoMeter() + " km passed.");
            System.out.println("Car 2 " + car2.printDashes(car2.getOdoMeter()) + " :" + car2.getOdoMeter() + " km passed.");
            System.out.println("Car 3 " + car3.printDashes(car3.getOdoMeter()) + " :" + car3.getOdoMeter() + " km passed.");
            System.out.println("Car 4 " + car4.printDashes(car4.getOdoMeter()) + " :" + car4.getOdoMeter() + " km passed.");
            System.out.println("Car 5 " + car5.printDashes(car5.getOdoMeter()) + " :" + car5.getOdoMeter() + " km passed.");

            car1.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));
            car2.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));
            car3.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));
            car4.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));
            car5.setSpeed(rand.nextInt(501));
        
        }

        if (car1.getTotalDistance() > car2.getTotalDistance() && 
            car1.getTotalDistance() > car2.getTotalDistance() &&
            car1.getTotalDistance() > car2.getTotalDistance() &&
            car1.getTotalDistance() > car2.getTotalDistance() &&
            car1.getTotalDistance() > car2.getTotalDistance() &&
            ) 
        

        input.close();

    }

}
```

So basically, I want to find which Car has the most total distance traveled. I know I can do it in a messy way by comparing Car 1's total distance with the other 4 cars etc etc but I'm hoping to find a more elegant and simpler way to do it, possibly within the boundaries of OOP and it's practices.

I'm hoping I can find a way to make a private method in the AutomaticCar Class that I can just call to declare the winner with it's total distance - but then, I don't know if I can tell which car's total distance is being declared as the most total distance..

So if there is any other way to do it - please comment below, thank you.

Comment: You could put all the cars in a `List`, sort the list on the basis of distance traveled. After sorting, car at the last index in the `List` will have the highest distance traveled or at the first index if you sort in descending order.

Comment: I could definitely use a List but it's a topic we haven't gone over so I probably shouldn't use it ..

Comment: You could also keep a separate reference to the car with max distance traveled by writing some code in the `setTotalDistance` method that checks if the total distance of current instance is greater than the distance traveled of the saved car's instance. If its is greater, then update the reference to point to the current car instance.